# Print file using 'Print to File' printer from terminal without installing any packages

Tags: command-line, printing

[image: Print to File using GNOME user interface]

How to do this using CLI? Other solutions require us to install third-party packages. I am asking for a native way, please do not mark this as a duplicate.

This printer is not shown anywhere, hence cant print using this printer.

```
$ lpstat -p -d
lpstat: No destinations added.
no system default destination
$ lpr -P "Print_to_PDF" file.pdf
lpr: No such file or directory
```

If not possible, can I invoke it from the Go code?

The `cupsfilter` and `enscript` solutions do not produce the same result as printing [using the user interface](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/printing-to-file.html.en). For example, metadata is not stripped out.

Comment: does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19126899/print-command-line-output-into-a-text-file-in-linux-ubuntu

Comment: Not at all. I think my question is not clear. Let me reframe - Print file to PDF using 'Print to File' printer using CLI... My English !! :(

Answer (score 1):

Accessing GTK's 'Print to File' entry using the command line is not possible. The feature does not access CUPS at all, so it is doubtful it deserves to be called a printer. What likely happens is that Cairo is invoked to render the page displayed as a PDF.

There does not appear to be any command that does what you want. In other words, as your question is formulated, there's no answer to it.

Comment: _Cairo is invoked to render the page displayed as a PDF from_ The answer is to reverse engineer the GTK code and rewrite it. Right?